# Separating two tables side by side in a MS Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, c#-3.0, excel-interop

When I am creating two tables side by side, any filter applied to the first table affects the second one. I want them to be separate entities and this aforementioned thing to stop. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Filtering affects the entire sheet, which is one good reason not to put tables next to each other.

Comment: Can you provide me with any suitable replacement?

Comment: @SourishAtorthy Either put them on separate sheets, or put them below each other.

Comment: Although this didn't solve my problem, but it worked. Thanks.

Can we write a code or something to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Separate the tables with blank columns

Comment: Sorry, yes of course it doesn't - don't know what I was thinking - filtering works by setting row heights to zero so it affects across the sheet.